# Hibernate and removing rownum statement

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g

I´m using Oracle 10G. My problem is, if I don´t set the `maxResults` method, Hibernate is unnecessarily appending a `rownum` statement at the end of the query. How could I get rid of this `rownum` statement?

Comment: To the close voter: I doubt many dba's would know or care about the behaviour of Hibernate. I'd say the answer is more likely to come from someone here on SO.

Comment: what `rownum` statement is hibernate adding - i.e. is it adding `where rownum = 1` or some higher number?

Comment: What is "the" query? How do you execute it?